# configuring log4j.properties file | separating logs

Tags: log4j

I am using hibernate in my webpoject.I have my log4j.propertes under WEB-INF/classes.I want seperate log files for hibernate logs and my application log.In shot am not interested in hibernate logs but am interested only in my application log.

I have following in my log4j.properties

```
# Define the root logger with appender file
logDir = ${catalina.home}/logs/akp.log
log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, FILE

#Define the file appender
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.FILE.File= ${catalina.home}/logs/${fileName}.log
```

And within my app i am getting a instance of my logger as

```
private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

But in logs folder i can see only one file with exmpt name : .log (not xyz.log).Also withing this name i have all mixed logs.I want seperate log file for each of my applation class as i am using

```
 logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you replace "filename" in ${fileName}?
Is it creating the log files under catalina.home folder, if not check if your catalina.home is declared?

Comment: Pre-processing of `log4j.properties` and manual substitution is very rare, although [possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783365/log4j-runtime-variable-substitution/1870034#1870034). Log4j does this substitution based on system variables. Usually they are defined in Tomcat start file.

Comment: its creating the log file @ C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.11\logs so i think catalina_home is declared.Also if i do echo %CATLINA_HOME% in command prompt i get C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 7.0.11\.What can be the possible problem.How can i configure my log4j.properties file so that i dont get any hibernate logs and i get only my application specific logs

Answer (score 1):

your log4j properties file is declaring variables but not using them. You've also got a couple of other issues and have asked about three separate questions.

Here you define the variable 'logDir':

> logDir = ${catalina.home}/logs/akp.log
>    (you are mixing up file name and directory here)

Here you use the variable 'fileName' and are not referring to logDir at all

> log4j.appender.FILE.File= ${catalina.home}/logs/${fileName}.log

You need to change a fair bit to achieve what you've described (there are also a vast range of other options and implications) but here's a start - declare your directory and file name separately:

> logDir = ${catalina.home}/logs
>   fileName = myAppLog.log

specify the root category appender (using a better naming convention than 'FILE'). Personally I'd never use DEBUG at the root unless it was a very small app:

> log4j.rootLogger = DEBUG, myAppAppender

Create the appender using the log directory and filename. Use append to add to decide whether to add to existing file or overwrite:

> log4j.appender.myAppAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
>   log4j.appender.myAppAppender.File= ${logDir}/${fileName}
>   log4j.appender.myAppAppender.Append=true

You can then specify additional appenders (and files) for different application categories. Parameterise the filename as needed/convenient, use additivity=false to keep the entry only in this specific log:

> log4j.category.com.company.package.specialpackagename=INFO, specialAppender
>   log4j.appender.specialAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
>   log4j.appender.specialAppender.File=${logDir}/specialPackageLog.log
>   log4j.appender.specialAppender.Append=true
>   log4j.appender.specialAppender.Additivity=false

That should get you started (if you've not got it already :)

cheers

Rob

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem where I was using *log4j.properties* and the purpose was to push logs from one package hierarchy into one file and the logs from a different package hierarchy in second file.

Although there is an answer accepted for this question, still I am just writing this to help people who are not able to configure this.

We need to configure appenders for each logger and define two loggers as below:

```
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.metering_app=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.metering_app.File=C:/logs/Metering_INFO.log 
log4j.appender.metering_app.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.metering_app.MaxBackupIndex=50
log4j.appender.metering_app.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.metering_app.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{2}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.metering_app.filter.ID=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.metering_app.filter.ID.LevelMax=FATAL
log4j.appender.metering_app.filter.ID.LevelMin=INFO
log4j.appender.metering_app.filter.ID.AcceptOnMatch=true


# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.notification_app=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.notification_app.File=C:/logs/Notification_INFO.log 
log4j.appender.notification_app.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.notification_app.MaxBackupIndex=50
log4j.appender.notification_app.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.notification_app.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,SSS} %5p %c{2}:%L - %m%n
log4j.appender.notification_app.filter.ID=org.apache.log4j.varia.LevelRangeFilter
log4j.appender.notification_app.filter.ID.LevelMax=FATAL
log4j.appender.notification_app.filter.ID.LevelMin=INFO
log4j.appender.notification_app.filter.ID.AcceptOnMatch=true

#root logger
log4j.logger.com.test.metering=INFO, metering_app
log4j.additivity.com.test.metering=false
log4j.logger.com.test.notification=INFO, notification_app
log4j.additivity.com.test.notification=false
```